# PIC16F18855 ADC registers aren't behaving the way I expect them to (C, CCS compiler)

Tags: c, embedded, pic, adc

I'm using a PIC16F18855 micro with CCS as the compiler, and I'm trying to get the ADC to work. Starting with the functions supplied by CCS, I wrote:

```
#device ADC=10
...
setup_adc_ports(sAN21);
setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_DIV_8);
set_adc_channel(21);
...
fprintf(HOST, "%ld", read_adc()); //I have RS232 implemented elsewhere
```

This was behaving strangely, with the readings that were completely independent of the actual voltage on the pin (randomly between 9 and 18 for a 10 bit reading).

A coworker looked through the assembly that the C compiled to, and tells me that the compiler is writing to the wrong register when it tries to read the adc using the built in `read_adc()` function. Specifically, when it should be writing the ADGO bit to start conversion it writes to the register before ADCON0 which doesn't exist.

To work around this, I tried to implement my own functions for setting up and reading the ADC:

```
#byte ADC_CON_0 = getenv("SFR:ADCON0")
#byte ADC_CON_1 = getenv("SFR:ADCON1")
#byte ADC_CON_2 = getenv("SFR:ADCON2")
#byte ADC_CON_3 = getenv("SFR:ADCON3")
#byte ADC_CLK   = getenv("SFR:ADCLK")
#byte ADC_RES_H = getenv("SFR:ADRESH")
#byte ADC_RES_L = getenv("SFR:ADRESL")
#byte AN_SEL_C  = getenv("SFR:ANSELC")
#byte ADC_PCH   = getenv("SFR:ADPCH")

void adc_setup(void){
    //setting the mode and clock
    ADC_CON_0 = 0x84;   //turn on ADC and right justify it
    ADC_CON_1 = 0x00;
    ADC_CON_2 = 0x00;
    ADC_CON_3 = 0x00;
    ADC_CLK   = 0x03;   //gives Fosc/8, for 1us T_AD with 8MHz clock

    //setting the input channel and telling the pin to be analogue
    AN_SEL_C  = 0x20;   //set pin C5 to analogue input
    ADC_PCH   = 0x15;   //0x15 = 21, analogue channel 21 is pin C5
}

int16 read_adc_custom_implementation(void){
    ADC_CON_0 |= 0x01;                      //set ADGO bit to start conversion
    while(ADC_CON_0 & 0x01){}               //wait till conversion is finished (indicated by hardware reset of ADGO bit)
    return make16(ADC_RES_H, ADC_RES_L);    //read the result registers and return them combined into a 16bit integer
}
```

There are two major problems with my code:

If I call `fprintf(HOST, "0x%x", ADC_CON_0);` immediately after calling `adc_setup();` I get `0x80` when I expected `0x84`. That means that the 10 bit adc value is left aligned within the 2 8 bit registers, rather than right aligned. I have no idea why it doesn't write correctly. Every other register I've checked (ADCON1-3 and ADCLK) is correct.

When I call `read_adc_custom_implementation();` it waits forever on the while loop, indicating that the ADGO bit is never reset as the datasheet indicates it should be.

Does anyone know why my implementations of `adc_setup` and `read_adc_custom_implementation` aren't working? Alternatively, if anyone knows why the supplied functions from CCS weren't working I'd be happy if I could use those instead.

[PIC16F18855 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/400001802D.pdf), ADCON0 is on page 357.

Comment: What type does `read_adc()` return?  Post the definition of `read_adc()`.

Comment: from the CCS manual: Either a 8 or 16 bit int depending on #DEVICE ADC= directive. because I'm using #device adc=10 its int16.

Comment: Instead of `l`  for `long`, ,use `fprintf(HOST, "%d", (int) read_adc());`

Comment: Just tried this. I get exactly the same result - numbers from 9-18 that have no correlation to the voltage on the pin. When I first tried I was using #device adc=8 and everything was set up for 8 bit integers. The results were identical, except instead of values from 9-18 I was getting values from 2-4, which counting the increased accuracy in the 10 bit value are the same reading with a left shift of 2

Comment: And what is the rest of the result register set to if you right-justify? Try `(int)(read_adc() & (1<<10 - 1))`. Also, does right justify mean "store data in data LSB and up" or does it mean "store data from bit n to bit 15"? Given that PIC is little endian, these are different things.

Comment: In a register in the PIC, bit 0 (LSB) is on the right and bit 7 (MSB) on the left. The result registers when left or right justified can be seen best in fig 23-3 on page 341 of the data sheet. All unimplemented bits are read as 0, so when right justified reading the two registers as a single int16 will give a value from 0-1023. when left justified, reading the registers in the same way will give the same result multiplied by 2 to the power 6, or a left shift of 6.
`read_adc` should take all of that into account though. All code examples show what I had in my first code snippet.

Comment: Try a 1-2ms delay after setting the register before checking it.  The A-D tends to be a bit slower than normal digital switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, with the help of a [user from the CCS forums](http://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=56864).

The bug I was encountering is a silicon bug - if you set the ADGO bit and then read it on the next clock cycle, the ADC never reset the ADGO bit. This means my while loop will wait forever. There are more details on this bug in the [errata](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/80000669D.pdf). I had actually read this before hand, but misinterpreted it as not applying to me because what was happening with my project wasn't the same as what is described in the document.

The workaround is to include a delay of a single clock cycle between setting the ADGO bit and checking it, ie:

```
int16 read_adc_custom_implementation(void){
    ADC_CON_0 |= 0x01;                      //set ADGO bit to start conversion
    delay_cycles(1);                        //workaround
    while(ADC_CON_0 & 0x01){}               //wait till conversion is finished (indicated by hardware reset of ADGO bit)
    return make16(ADC_RES_H, ADC_RES_L);    //read the result registers and return them combined into a 16bit integer
}
```

This workaround is included in the `read_adc()` function built into CCS in versions 5.069 and later, but I was using 5.065, which was the first version of the compiler to support the 18855. I first tried the workaround and it solved one of my problems, but I was still encountering a number of other bugs. 
Instead of trying to work around them, I updated to 5.075 and used the built in `read_adc()` function. Everything started working perfectly.

So long story short, if you have the same problem then update the compiler.